# pandas replace empty cell with value of another column

Tags: python, pandas

I want to replace the cells of column A with the value of column B, if the value of columns A is empty:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1, 2, '', 4, ''], 'B':[6, 7, 8, 9, 10]})
```

Should return:

```
   A   B
   1   6
   2   7
   8   8
   4   9
   10  10
```

I tried to replace the empty values of columns A but I got an

`"Series.replace cannot use dict-value and " ValueError: Series.replace cannot use dict-value and non-None to_replace`

```
df['A'] = df['A'].replace('', df['B'])
```

How can I replace the empty cells?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can replace '' by NA, then `bfill`:

```
df.replace('', pd.NA).bfill(axis=1)
```

Or use `fillna`:

```
df['A'] = df['A'].replace('', pd.NA).fillna(df['B'])
```

output:

```
    A   B
0   1   6
1   2   7
2   8   8
3   4   9
4  10  10
```